# How to send Firebase cloud messaging token to server after login in Angularjs web app?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-scope, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send firebase cloud messaging device token to server after the user log in but it is created on loading 'index.html' Page.

Here is my code:

```js
"Index.html"
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
            .then(function (registration) {

                var serviceWorker;
                if (registration.installing) {
                    serviceWorker = registration.installing;
                } else if (registration.waiting) {
                    serviceWorker = registration.waiting;
                } else if (registration.active) {
                    serviceWorker = registration.active;
                }
                // if (serviceWorker) {
                //     // console.log("ServiceWorker phase is:", serviceWorker.state);
                //     // registration.pushManager.subscribe({userVisibleOnly: true}).then(function (subscription) {
                //     //     isPushEnabled = true;
                //     //
                //     //     console.log("subscription.endpoint: ", subscription.endpoint);
                //     //
                //     //     // sendSubscriptionIDtoServer(subscription.endpoint);
                //     // });
                //
                // }
            }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
        });


        messaging.requestPermission()
            .then(function() {
                console.log('Notification permission granted.');
                messaging.getToken()
                    .then(function(currentToken) {
                        if (currentToken) {
                            console.log(currentToken);
                            localStorageService.set('fcmtoken',currentToken);
                            // sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
                            //updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
                        } else {
                            // Show permission request.
                            // console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                            // Show permission UI.
                            //updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
                            //setTokenSentToServer(false);
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        // console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
                        showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
                        setTokenSentToServer(false);
                    });
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                // console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
            });
        messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {

            console.log("Message received. ", payload);
            // ...
        });
```

In firebase-messaging-sw.js file ,

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');

// /*
// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the messagingSenderId.
// */
firebase.initializeApp({
    'messagingSenderId': '969941201331'
});

/*
Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background messages.
*/
var message = firebase.messaging();

message.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    // Customize notification here
    const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: 'Background Message body.',
        icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions);
});
```

But now I am not able to access these function in any other controller of my app. How can I **send device token along with user id** to server after user Log in?

How to access these function in any controller? Here **Index.html** is landing page of **website(login page).**

Answer (score 0):

messaging.getToken() is available globally.We can use it to do whatever required.